# When can we say that $a \ge b \ge c$ without loss of generality?

Tags: inequality, reference-request

I have seen a lot of problems solved by the method, we can say that $a \ge b \ge c$. without loss of generality". My question is when can we say this about a,b,c, because I realize through direct observation that we cannot always assume this?

For example, let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers. Prove that:

$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\ge\frac{3}{2}$$

and

$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\ge3$$

Comment: *"Without loss of generality"* or "without restricting equality" ?

Comment: @lonestudent oooo....sorry, now i realise. it's "without loss  of generality".

Comment: If you [edit] the question to provide a direct quote from someplace you have seen this we may be able to help. As written the question is too vague.

Comment: @EthanBolker I found out that i wrote the question wrong. I meant "without loss of generality"

Comment: Generally speaking: if $a,b,c$ have been defined to have exactly the same properties as one another, then one can order them without losing generality. But if some of $a,b,c$ have specific properties that the others don't share, then we can't assume they come in a particular order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a problem in which three numbers labelled "$a$", "$b$" and "$c$" appear and you know nothing else about them then you know they must be in some linear order. So you can just switch their *names* around so that they are in decreasing order. You do that if it makes the ensuing argument easier to read than if you worked out all six cases separately.

In general terms, the phrase "without loss of generality"
usually means the assumption that follows takes advantage of some symmetry in the hypotheses that leads to a simpler proof than the more general case seems to require.

See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality  and  https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Without_loss_of_generality

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!! These equations are called symmetrical equations or something?

Comment: @IonelaBuciu If you had symmetrical equations that's what you would call them but the "wlog" argument is useful in many places where there are no equations. There is usually some kind of underlying symmetry.